# I need to reset rest_length of Stretch To constraints using python but this doesn't work

Tags: python, bones, constraints

I need to mute all Transformation,Copy Location,Copy Rotation,and Copy Scale constraints to get pure rest_length number of Stretch To constraint, but there are lots of constraints so I need to use this python script.

I am using this python script. It resets selected bones' transformation and mutes Transformation,Copy Location,Copy Rotation,and Copy Scale constraints, and saves processed bones' names and constraints' names.After that it resets all rest_length of Stretch To constraints and re-activate Transformation,Copy Location,Copy Rotation,and Copy Scale constraints again.

But this just mutes Transformation,Copy Location,Copy Rotation,and Copy Scale and enable them all again. Seems Stretch Constraints are untouched.
Do you know why?

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
for b in context.selected_pose_bones_from_active_object:
    b.matrix_basis = Matrix() 
    
names =  set()
for b in bpy.context.selected_pose_bones:
    for c in b.constraints: 
        if c.type in ["TRANSFORM", "COPY_ROTATION", "COPY_LOCATION","COPY_SCALE"]:
            c.mute = True
            names.add(b.name)
            names.add(c.name)

for b in bpy.context.selected_pose_bones:     
    for c in b.constraints: 
            if c.type == "STRETCH_TO":
                c.rest_length = 0.0
             
for b in bpy.context.selected_pose_bones:  
    if b.name in names:
        for c in b.constraints: 
            if c.type in ["TRANSFORM", "COPY_ROTATION", "COPY_LOCATION","COPY_SCALE"]:
                if c.name in names:
                    c.mute = False
```

Answer (score 0):

this works fine.  Seems bpy.ops.screen.frame_jump() needs to be done before resetting Stretch to constraint.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix

# Reset Bones Transformation
context = bpy.context
for b in context.selected_pose_bones_from_active_object:
    b.matrix_basis = Matrix() 

# Mute other constraints and save names
names = set()
for b in bpy.context.selected_pose_bones:
    for c in b.constraints: 
        if c.type in ["TRANSFORM", "COPY_ROTATION", "COPY_LOCATION","COPY_SCALE"]:
            c.mute = True
            names.add(b.name)
            names.add(c.name)

# Update the constraints by jumping to the current frame
bpy.ops.screen.frame_jump()

# Reset rest length of stretch to constraints
for b in bpy.context.selected_pose_bones:     
    for c in b.constraints: 
        if c.type == "STRETCH_TO":
            c.rest_length = 0.0

# Mute constraints with saved names
for b in bpy.context.selected_pose_bones:  
    if b.name in names:
        for c in b.constraints: 
            if c.type in ["TRANSFORM", "COPY_ROTATION", "COPY_LOCATION","COPY_SCALE"]:
                if c.name in names:
                    c.mute = True

# Update the constraints by jumping to the current frame
bpy.ops.screen.frame_jump()

# Unmute constraints with saved names
for b in bpy.context.selected_pose_bones:  
    if b.name in names:
        for c in b.constraints: 
            if c.type in ["TRANSFORM", "COPY_ROTATION", "COPY_LOCATION","COPY_SCALE"]:
                if c.name in names:
                    c.mute = False
```